# extract the timestamp of specific item from data frame/table

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

I have a data set composed from 2 columns and around 12K rows. It have this form

```
timestamp  track 
0.006       A
0.185       R
0.210       A
0.221  R
0.285  A
0.387  R
0.405  R
0.412  R
0.436  A
0.458  A
0.482  A
```

So what i want is first to extract all the timestamp where my track is equal to A, which i did easily using so base R function

```
track_data = subset(df, df$track == 'A')
track_time = track_data$V1
```

now i want to extract the timestamp of the last track = R just before the last track = A if any R is founded if not to put a timestamp = 0

so in my case for example it would be:

(0, 0.185, 0.221, 0.412, 0.412, 0.412, ...)

obviously I should have a vector that contain as many element as the number of A in track vector.

I have tried to do a loop but the result is not compatible at all with what I am looking.

```
for (i in 1 : length(df$track)) {
 if (df$track[i] == 'A')
  x = last(df$track[i] == 'R')
 vect = c(vect,x)
 }
```

any help plz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### base R

We can create a vector of just-R timestamps, then use `zoo::na.locf` (last observation carried forward) to cascade it into the A rows.

```r
ifelse(dat$track == "R", dat$timestamp, NA)
#  [1]    NA 0.185    NA 0.221    NA 0.387 0.405 0.412    NA    NA    NA
zoo::na.locf(ifelse(dat$track == "R", dat$timestamp, NA), na.rm = FALSE)
#  [1]    NA 0.185 0.185 0.221 0.221 0.387 0.405 0.412 0.412 0.412 0.412
dat$newcol <- zoo::na.locf(ifelse(dat$track == "R", dat$timestamp, NA), na.rm = FALSE)
dat$newcol <- ifelse(is.na(dat$newcol), 0, dat$newcol)
dat
#    timestamp track newcol
# 1      0.006     A  0.000
# 2      0.185     R  0.185
# 3      0.210     A  0.185
# 4      0.221     R  0.221
# 5      0.285     A  0.221
# 6      0.387     R  0.387
# 7      0.405     R  0.405
# 8      0.412     R  0.412
# 9      0.436     A  0.412
# 10     0.458     A  0.412
# 11     0.482     A  0.412
subset(dat, track == "A")
#    timestamp track newcol
# 1      0.006     A  0.000
# 3      0.210     A  0.185
# 5      0.285     A  0.221
# 9      0.436     A  0.412
# 10     0.458     A  0.412
# 11     0.482     A  0.412
```

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  mutate(
    newcol = coalesce(
      zoo::na.locf(if_else(track == "R", timestamp, NA_real_), na.rm = FALSE),
      0)
  ) %>%
  filter(track == "A")
```

`coalesce` is a function that returns the first non-`NA` of the arguments, so this replaces our `ifelse(is.na(newcol),...)` from base R.

### data.table

```r
library(data.table)
datDT[, newcol := fcoalesce(
    nafill(fifelse(track == "R", timestamp, NA_real_), type = "locf"),
    0)]
```

`data.table` has its own `nafill` that replaces the need for `zoo::na.locf`, as well as its own `fifelse` and `fcoalesce`.